# Emploi du pluriel "formulæ" en français

Tags: pluriel, mathématiques, latin

> Then we construct substitution formulæ valid for...
>
> Ensuite, nous construisons des formulæ de substitution valables pour...

Peut-on utiliser en français le pluriel latin formulæ ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Non, parce que le singulier est *formule*, pas *formula*. C'est un mot français parfaitement normal, qui existait déjà en ancien français, et pas un emprunt au latin.

Il ne me vient pas à l'esprit de nom latin en -a de la première déclinaison qui soit utilisé ordinairement en français, et il n'y en a pas sur [cette liste](https://www.espacefrancais.com/les-mots-latins-admis-en-francais/). (Il y a quelques emprunts au latin qui se terminent par -a, mais ils ont une autre formation, par exemple des pluriels neutres en général empruntés comme noms masculins.) C'est probablement parce que la finale -a est très proche de sa francisation -e, donc la francisation se fait systématiquement.

En français, il est toujours correct d'utiliser la règle générale du français pour former le pluriel d'un nom emprunté : ajout de -s sauf si le mot se termine déjà par S, X ou Z. C'est aussi bien ce que préconise [l'Académie française](http://www.academie-francaise.fr/un-stimuli) que [la Banque de dépannage linguistique du Québec](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=1030). On admet en général aussi le pluriel emprunté (ou l'invariance lorsque le mot emprunté n'est pas un nom singulier : nom pluriel, verbe, adverbe, etc.). Le choix entre les deux formes du pluriel varie suivant les mots et les usages.

Comment: pour info, je pense que c'est le cas de "radula" (n.f. pour la "langue" de l'escargot), le même mot étant par ailleurs également utilisé en anglais. Si je ne me trompe, il prend un "s" au pluriel en français, comme vous l'indiquez, mais peut s'écrire radulae dans le pluriel anglais.

Answer (score 3):

Ni *formulæ* ni *formulae* ne se rencontrent dans des textes en français, d'autant plus que *formula* n'est pas non plus utilisé  au singulier.

On utilise donc simplement le pluriel régulier de *formule* :

> Ensuite, nous construisons des formules de substitution valables pour...

Comment: C'est surtout que le singulier est *formule*, pas *formula*.

Answer (score 2):

en somme, nous sommes trop proches du latin pour emprunter tels quels ses mots … Cela dit, on parle d'une facture pro forma (ablatif de la 1re déclinaison) et de personna non grata (oh-oh, en cas d'expulsion de plusieurs diplomates ex-soviétiques mais vrais espions, dirait-on personnae non gratae ?), c'est du latin pur, les opticiens parlent aussi de macula (au centre de la rétine) et de fovea (au centre de la … macula), a priori le pluriel se fait en « s », horresco referens!

Quant à la ligature, je suis surpris de son emploi en anglais, il me semblait que les anglophones ne l'employaient guère.

Comment: Concernant la ligature en anglais, à défaut de certitudes (à ce jour) sur [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86#English), on pourra toujours trouver [ce groupe de chanteuses](https://www.mediaevalbaebes.com/music/), dont l’usage varie en fonction de la facilité d’accès à la ligature (surtout *ae* sur leurs sites et comptes, clairement *æ* quand vient le temps du logo).

Comment: @Montée de lait – mais ne s'agit-il pas alors plutôt d'un clin d'œil au Æ (æsc) anglo-saxon, du vieil-anglais donc ? je pensais plutôt à la ligature latine ou française, d'ailleurs moins utilisée que ne le dit Wikipedia, même en latin nous n'avions pas le droit d'en user depuis l'adoption de la prononciation restituée et l'abandon lent des lettres ramusiennes …